# PHP / PostgreSQL while and foreach loops skipping first record

Tags: php, postgresql, foreach, html-table, while-loop

I'm testing outputting queries into `html` tables but for some reason I can't figure out why the first record of the queries are skipped.

Suppose I have my query as
`$userResults = pg_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users;");`

And my `table` as;

```
<table id='table1'>
    <div id='t1' class='table100-head'>
        <thead>
            <tr class='row100 head' id="tblHeader">
                <!-- Table header -->
                <?php
                    $header = pg_fetch_assoc($userResults);

                    foreach ($header as $column => $value) {
                        $columnName = trim($column,"'");
                        echo "<th class='cell100 column2'>" . $columnName . "</th>";
                    }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </div>
    <div class='table100-body js-pscroll'>
        <tbody id="tblBody">
            <?php
                while ($body = pg_fetch_assoc($userResults)) {
                    echo "<tr class='row100 body'>";
                        foreach ($body as $column2 => $value2) {
                            echo "<td class='cell100 column2'>" . $value2 . "</td>";
                        }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </div>
</table>
```

The above would result in all the rows as expected in the `<tbody>` except the very first record. If for instance say the results had user_id's from 1 to 10, only 2 to 10 would appear.

I know it has to do with the loops but I can't point out where exactly. The reason I don't want to use a while loop exclusively is because;

1. I don't want to have to programatically specify the column names.
2. The column names will differ from user to user

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's because you are running pg_fetch_assoc to get the headers which loads the first record and when you call it again from the while it moves the cursor to the second record. Keep the values from the for each and echo them before the while as the first row, or think of a better way to get your columns.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the code after the `pg_query()` is exactly as I've put it in the question. I haven't left out anything.

Comment: You could have $printedHeaders = false; while fetch { if !$printedHeader, print headers. Continue with printing columns }

Comment: @JackWilko that actually sounds like the problem. Let me try a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching the first on the first iteration when displaying the headers. the call `pg_fetch_assoc($userResults)` will get the next row. 
You need to set the Set internal row offset in result resource to 0. before starting the next iteration. use:

```
pg_result_seek($userResults, 0);
```

You should end up with something like this: 
...

```
<?php
    pg_result_seek($userResults, 0);
    while ($body = pg_fetch_assoc($userResults)) {
        echo "<tr class='row100 body'>";
        foreach ($body as $column2 => $value2) {
           echo "<td class='cell100 column2'>" . $value2 . "</td>";
        }      
        echo "</tr>";
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a do-while,

```
<table id='table1'>
<div id='t1' class='table100-head'>
    <thead>
        <tr class='row100 head' id="tblHeader">
            <!-- Table header -->
            <?php
                $header = pg_fetch_assoc($userResults);

                foreach ($header as $column => $value) {
                    $columnName = trim($column,"'");
                    echo "<th class='cell100 column2'>" . $columnName . "</th>";
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</div>
<div class='table100-body js-pscroll'>
    <tbody id="tblBody">
        <?php
            do {
                echo "<tr class='row100 body'>";
                    foreach ($body as $column2 => $value2) {
                        echo "<td class='cell100 column2'>" . $value2 . "</td>";
                    }
                echo "</tr>";
            } while ($body = pg_fetch_assoc($userResults)) 
        ?>
    </tbody>
</div>
```

Comment: But your Do-While is not referenceing `$header` so this is not going to help. In fact it should generate an error